# How to push params to Url in Angular2 Router@3 without page reload

Tags: angular, router, query-string

How can I push query params (page, limit) to url in angular, preferably without navigation.

I'm using the new, vladivostok router (npm [@angular/router@3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/router)) and I have a table with paging. So when I click "next page" or change the number of items per page, I want to have that in the url.

I know I can programatically `router.navigateByUrl('/users?page=3')` or similar, but can I avoid navigating at all and just update the url? My services will reload the table and everything as needed. Or is that not the way to go?

Comment: What is happening when the current page is `/users?page=3` and you navigate to `/users?page=4`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it should update. I'll try the window.history answer.

Comment: AFAIK this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) would do the trick:

```js
window.history.pushState(null, "pagetitle", "users?page=4");
```